# Equal sign in function prototype

Tags: c++, stl, function-prototypes

I was checking the reference for the STL `vector` container's constructor, and I see one of the prototypes listed is this:

```
explicit vector(size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type(),
             const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

Link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

Could anyone explain what the `=` in the second and third parameters mean?